# Flagging privilege help center page is outdated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, flags, privileges, help-center

[Flagging options were recently re-worded network-wide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290915/1234256). Good.

However, the network-wide help center page on the flagging privilege retains the old wording and screenshots of it. ([MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) | [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) | [LH](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts))

Please update. You're confusing us new users.

Comment: They'll probably get around to it once they iron out the exact wording and placement of the new things.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn True, but it's still an issue in the time being.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I agree. This is one of a long list of situations in which sections of the help pages are confusing, or obsolete. Other than voting up this question, which an average user doesn't even know exists, how can we effect change?

Comment: I think this privilege help page was updated a while back to address these issues (and I updated it again a few months ago), so I'll go ahead and mark this as [status-completed] now.